# Can Google Chrome be installed on Solaris 10?

Tags: google-chrome, solaris, solaris-10

If so, how do I do it?

Comment: I'm no expert, but a quick Google search shows a lot of people asking for the ability, so I'm assuming 'no'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Step 1: Help finish the port: http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=30101

Answer (score -1):

This guy ported Chromium to Solaris 10 and offer the builds to paid subscribers here:
http://chromium.hybridsource.org/